# Solution for SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported while agg() along with groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

```
def stack_plot(data, xtick, col2='project_is_approved', col3='total'):
    ind = np.arange(data.shape[0])

    plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
    p1 = plt.bar(ind, data[col3].values)
    p2 = plt.bar(ind, data[col2].values)

    plt.ylabel('Projects')
    plt.title('Number of projects aproved vs rejected')
    plt.xticks(ind, list(data[xtick].values))
    plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('total', 'accepted'))
    plt.show()

def univariate_barplots(data, col1, col2='project_is_approved', top=False):
    # Count number of zeros in dataframe python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540521/4084039
    temp = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg(lambda x: x.eq(1).sum())).reset_index()

    # Pandas dataframe grouby count: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19385591/4084039
    temp['total'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg({'total':'count'})).reset_index()['total']

    temp['Avg'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg({'Avg':'mean'})).reset_index()['Avg']

    temp.sort_values(by=['total'],inplace=True, ascending=False)

    if top:
        temp = temp[0:top]

    stack_plot(temp, xtick=col1, col2=col2, col3='total')
    print(temp.head(5))
    print("="*50)
    print(temp.tail(5))

univariate_barplots(project_data, 'school_state', 'project_is_approved', False)
```

Error:

```
SpecificationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-2cace8f16608> in <module>()
----> 1 univariate_barplots(project_data, 'school_state', 'project_is_approved', False)

<ipython-input-20-856fcc83737b> in univariate_barplots(data, col1, col2, top)
      4 
      5     # Pandas dataframe grouby count: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19385591/4084039
----> 6     temp['total'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg({'total':'count'})).reset_index()['total']
      7     print (temp['total'].head(2))
      8     temp['Avg'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg({'Avg':'mean'})).reset_index()['Avg']

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    251             # but not the class list / tuple itself.
    252             func = _maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
--> 253             ret = self._aggregate_multiple_funcs(func)
    254             if relabeling:
    255                 ret.columns = columns

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg)
    292             # GH 15931
    293             if isinstance(self._selected_obj, Series):
--> 294                 raise SpecificationError("nested renamer is not supported")
    295 
    296             columns = list(arg.keys())

SpecificationError: **nested renamer is not supported**
```

Comment: As much as code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, so is code-only posts. Please explain something of this process.

Comment: You may also get this error if you try to aggregate and one or more of the columns are not present in the data frame

Comment: @ConfusionMatrix wish I had seen this earlier - this was a very useful pointer with the not-so-intuitive error message. Thank you!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In this specific case you can change

```py
temp['total'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg({'total':'count'})).reset_index()['total']

temp['Avg'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg({'Avg':'mean'})).reset_index()['Avg']
```

to the new syntax

```py
temp['total'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg(total='count')).reset_index()['total']
temp['Avg'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg(Avg='mean')).reset_index()['Avg']
```

New syntax:

```py
df.groupby(
    [columns]
).agg(
    new_column_name=("column", aggregation_function)
)
```

The reason for this is that the new pandas version *named aggregation* is the recommended replacement for the deprecated *dict-of-dicts* approach to naming the output of column-specific aggregations [(Deprecate groupby.agg() with a dictionary when renaming).](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-group-agg-dict)

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html

Comment: how would you put multiple function inside the aggregate ? for example adding min and max too

Comment: add them as keyword arguments, like `.agg(avg="mean", total="count")`

Answer (score 61):

This error also happens if a column specified in the aggregation function dict does not exist in the dataframe:

```py
In [190]: group = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=['A', 'B']).groupby('A')
In [195]: group.agg({'B': 'mean'})
Out[195]: 
   B
A   
1  2

In [196]: group.agg({'B': 'mean', 'non-existing-column': 'mean'})
...
SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported
```

Comment: This answer points to the actual source of the error.  The other answer indicating there is another way to specify may be true but does not get to the root cause.

Answer (score 6):

I found the way: Instead of going like

```
g2 = df.groupby(["Description","CustomerID"],as_index=False).agg({'Quantity':{"maxQ":np.max,"minQ":np.min,"meanQ":np.mean}})
g2.columns = ["Description","CustomerID","maxQ","minQ",'meanQ']
```

Do as follows:

```
g2 = df.groupby(["Description","CustomerID"],as_index=False).agg({'Quantity':{np.max,np.min,np.mean}})
g2.columns = ["Description","CustomerID","maxQ","minQ",'meanQ']
```

I had the same error and this is how I resolved it!

Comment: Please note! The order of columns returned by group by is not the same as the order of aggregations included within 'agg'. If this is ignored, then all the numbers returned will be incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Do you get the same error if you change

```
temp['total'] = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg({'total':'count'})).reset_index()['total']
```

to

```
temp['total'] = project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg(total=('total','count')).reset_index()['total']
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `.agg({'total':'count'}))`, you can pass name with the function as a list of tuple like `.agg([('total', 'count')])`and use the same for `Avg` also. Hope it would work.

Comment: This solution has the benefit of having the resulting columns named appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the similar issue as @akshay jindal, but I check the documentation as suggested by @artikay Khanna, the problem solved, some functions has been adjusted, the old is deprecated. Here is the code warning provided per last time execute.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use                 named aggregation instead.

    >>> grouper.agg(name_1=func_1, name_2=func_2)

  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Therefore, I will suggest try

```
grouper.agg(name_1=func_1, name_2=func_2)
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Not a very elegant solution but this one works. As renaming the column is deprecated with the way you are doing. But there is work around. Create a temporary variable '**approved**' , store the **col2** in it. Because when you apply agg function , the original column values will change with column name. You can preserve the column name but then values in those column will change. So in order to preserve the original dataframe and to have two new columns with desired names, you can use the following code.

```
approved = temp[col2]
temp = pd.DataFrame(project_data.groupby(col1)[col2].agg([('Avg','mean'),('total','count')]).reset_index())
temp[col2] = approved
```

P.S : Seems like an assignment of AAIC, I am working on same :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's convenient to keep an `aggdict` of how each column should be transformed under aggregation that will work with different column sets and different group by columns. You can do this with the new syntax fairly easily by unpacking the dict with **. Here's a minimal working example for simple data.

```
dfx=pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C"],data=np.random.randint(0,5,size=(10,3)))
#dfx
#
#   A  B  C
#0  4  4  1
#1  2  4  4
#2  1  3  3
#3  2  4  3
#4  1  2  1
#5  0  4  2
#6  2  3  4
#7  1  0  2
#8  2  1  4
#9  3  0  3
```

Maybe when you agg you want the first `"A"`, the last `"B"`, the mean `"C"` and sometimes your pipeline has a `"D"` (but not this time) that you also want the mean of.

```
aggdict = {"A":lambda x: x.iloc[0], "B": lambda x: x.iloc[-1], "C" : "mean" , "D":lambda x: "mean"}
```

You can build a simple `dict` like the old days and then unpack it with ** filtering on the relevant keys:

```
gb_col="C"
gbc = dfx.groupby(gb_col).agg(**{k:(k,v) for k,v in aggdict.items() if k in dfx.columns and k != gb_col})
#       A  B
#C      
#1  4  2
#2  0  0
#3  1  4
#4  2  3
```

And then you can slice and dice how you want with the same syntax:

```
mygb = lambda gb_col: dfx.groupby(gb_col).agg(**{k:(k,v) for k,v in aggdict.items() if k in dfx.columns and k != gb_col})
allgb = [mygb(c) for c in dfx.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried alll the solutions and turned out to be the error with the name. If your column name has some inbuilt keywords such as "in", "is",etc., It is throwing error. In my case, My column name is "Points in Polygon" and I have resolved the issue by renaming the column to "Points"

Answer (score 0):

@Rishi's solution worked for me. The original name of the column in my dataframe was `net_value_budgeted_rate`, which was essentially dollar value of the sale. I changed it to `dollars` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
Info = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("school_state").agg(Approved=("project_is_approved",lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()),Total=("project_is_approved","count"),Avg=("project_is_approved","mean"))).reset_index().sort_values(by=["Total"],ascending=False).head()
```

You can break this into individual commands for better readability.